# Terraform - Ignore/circumvent Self-referential block

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

I am trying to use this provider, https://registry.terraform.io/providers/jgrumboe/restapi/1.18.3-dev
Which is a spin off of,
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/Mastercard/restapi/1.17.0

These providers let you automate APIs that follow REST standards to GET/POST/PUT and DELETE resources.

Now, the resource restapi_object allows you to specify, "data" that'll be used during a POST and "update_data" will be used during a PUT.

```
resource "restapi_object" "app_scripted_demo_client" {
  provider = restapi.restapi_oauth
  path     = "/Applications"
  data = jsonencode({
    "Uuid": random_uuid.app_scripted_demo_client_uuid.id,
    "Name": "Scripted Demo Client"
    }
  })

  update_data = jsonencode({
    "Uuid": random_uuid.app_scripted_demo_client_uuid.id,
    "Name": "Scripted Demo Client 1",
    "ApiKey": try(restapi_object.app_scripted_demo_client.api_data.ApiKey, "dummykey"),
    "KeySecret": try(restapi_object.app_scripted_demo_client.api_data.KeySecret, "dummysecret")
    }
  })
}
```

update_data takes two vars called, ApiKey and KeySecret, that's created during a POST.
When I refer to them using the same resource I get errors like these,

```
│ Error: Self-referential block
│
│   on apps.tf line 49, in resource "restapi_object" "app_scripted_demo_client":
│   49:     "ApiKey": try(restapi_object.app_scripted_demo_client.api_data.ApiKey, "dummykey"),
│
│ Configuration for restapi_object.app_scripted_demo_client may not refer to itself.
```

I understand terraform doesn't know that "update_data" is only used after the resource is created.
Is there a way to circumvent the error?

I tried using local vars like this,

```
locals {
  app_scripted_demo_client_key = try(restapi_object.app_scripted_demo_client.api_data.ApiKey, "dummykey")
  app_scripted_demo_client_secret = try(restapi_object.app_scripted_demo_client.api_data.KeySecret, "dummysecret")
}
```

They throw a similar error like this,

```
│ Error: Cycle: local.app_scripted_demo_client_secret (expand), restapi_object.app_scripted_demo_client, local.app_scripted_demo_client_key (expand)
```

Comment: This is not going to be possible, but also this is rather unusual for a REST API to return credentials during a POST that would then be used during a PUT.

Comment: Simply put, no. You can't reference something inside itself. You could create a separate resource or data source maybe that yields this data, and reference it here, but I'm not sure how to implement this provider so ymmv.